# How do I plot percentages for multiple response questions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I am trying to analyse a survey in which multiple responses are allowed for the same respondent. The goal is to determine the number of participants within each class that gave each of 3 possible responses, in order to plot it on a bar graph.

So for example, if my data frame `df` looks like follows:

| ID | q1 | q2 | q3 | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | cat | dog | NA | A |
| 002 | cat | NA | bird | A |
| 003 | NA | dog | bird | A |
| 004 | NA | dog | NA | B |
| 005 | cat | dog | NA | B |
| 006 | NA | dog | bird | B |
| 007 | cat | dog | bird | C |
| 008 | NA | dog | NA | C |

I would like to determine the percentage of respondents in class A, B, and C, respectively, who gave each answer. My expected answer looks like this:

| class | q | perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | cat | 0.67 |
| A | dog | 0.67 |
| A | bird | 0.67 |
| B | cat | 0.33 |
| B | dog | 1.00 |
| B | bird | 0.33 |
| C | cat | 0.50 |
| C | dog | 1.00 |
| C | bird | 0.50 |

I would like to keep my answer as a data frame, since I would like to use the `ggplot2` package to combine my resulting frequencies with other variables that I have (like the variable `cls` in the data frame above.

Right now I'm only able to determine the raw frequencies, since whenever I try to plot the percentages, I get the percentage with respect to the total number of answers per category. For example, for category A, I get:
|class| q |perc|
|--|--|--|
|A| cat |0.33|
|A| dog |0.33|
|A| bird |0.33|

Here's what I've tried:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

idno <- 1:8
q1 <- c('cat','cat',NA, NA, 'cat',NA,'cat',NA)
q2 <- c('dog',NA,'dog','dog','dog','dog','dog','dog')
q3 <- c(NA,'bird','bird',NA,NA,'bird','bird',NA)
cls <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C')

df <- data.frame(idno,q1,q2,q3,cls)

df1 <- gather(df,"animal","ans",2:4)
ggplot(df1[!is.na(df1$ans),], aes(x=ans, group=cls)) + geom_bar(aes(y=..prop..,fill=cls),position='dodge')
```

Is there a way in which I can divide the frequency for each subcategory not by the *number of answers* but rather by the *number of respondents* in that category?

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHp1O.png)

Answer (score 1):

You must set the aesthetics `y` and `label` to `..prop..` and the `position`'s width. `vjust` justifies the labels within the bars.

```
ggplot(df1[!is.na(df1$ans),], aes(x = ans, group = cls, fill = cls)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ..prop.., label = scales::percent(..prop..)),
            stat = 'count', position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question since, for example, you get 25% of the answers from category C being bird. However, what I want to see is that 50% of the respondents from category C gave "bird" as one of their answers.